# making text bold via code

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the code:

```
label5.Font = new Font(label5.Font.Name, 12, FontStyle.Underline);
```

..But I can't figure how to change it to bold as well. How can I do that?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use `|` to combine multiple styles:

```
label5.Font = new Font(label5.Font.Name, 12, FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold);
```